# In app billing IAB setup successful but queryInventory reports IAB helper not set up

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to implement in app billing. I have used the trivialdrivesample as it is.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // load game data
    loadData();


    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "my key";



    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
          //  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
Button purchaseB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.purchase_button);

 if(purchaseB != null)
     purchaseB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

         onUpgradeAppButtonClicked(null);

      }
  });
```

Its working perfectly and I am able to purchase from my test account.

But problem is that I have to comment the code line

//  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
SO I am not able to query inventory. On dubugging I found that variable

```
// Is setup done?
    boolean mSetupDone = false;
```

in IabHelper class is false and it raises an exception. The log just after saying setup successfull its saying IAB helper not setup.

---

```
08-02 16:02:42.453: D/PackList(10346): Creating IAB helper.
08-02 16:02:42.453: D/PackList(10346): Starting setup.
08-02 16:02:42.468: D/IabHelper(10346): Starting in-app billing setup.
08-02 16:02:42.515: D/PackList(10346): Creating IAB helper.
08-02 16:02:42.539: D/IabHelper(10346): Billing service connected.
08-02 16:02:42.546: D/IabHelper(10346): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
08-02 16:02:42.562: D/IabHelper(10346): In-app billing version 3 supported for com.xx
08-02 16:02:42.570: D/IabHelper(10346): Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
08-02 16:02:42.570: D/PackList(10346): Setup finished.
08-02 16:02:42.570: D/PackList(10346): Setup successful. Querying inventory.
08-02 16:02:42.578: E/IabHelper(10346): In-app billing error: Illegal state for operation (queryInventory): IAB helper is not set up.
```

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944522/google-in-app-billing-causing-exception/17960318#17960318

Comment: See this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/13981478/2106820

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Setting up:

```
mIabHelper = new IabHelper(this, ProjectKonstants.APP_PUBLIC_KEY_GOOGLE_PLAY);

mIabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
{
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
    {
        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mInitialInventoryListener);
        }
    }
});

mInitialInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener()
{
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
    {
        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            mBHasDonated = inventory.hasPurchase(ProjectKonstants.APPLICATION_SKU_FOR_DONATION);
        }
        else
        {
            mBHasDonated = false;
        }
    }
};

mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener()
{
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            if (purchase.getSku().equals(ProjectKonstants.APPLICATION_SKU_FOR_DONATION))
            {
                mBHasDonated = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        mBHasDonated = false;
    }
};
```

On Upgrade button clicked:

```
AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
String strIdentifier = "[" + accounts[0].name + "][" + android.os.Build.MODEL + "][" + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "]";
try
{
    mIabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ProjectKonstants.APPLICATION_SKU_FOR_DONATION, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, strIdentifier);
}
catch (IllegalStateException e)
{
}
```