# Android In-App Billing app works in some phones and stops in some another

Tags: android

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943950/in-app-billing-doesnt-work-iab-helper-is-not-set-up) solution , But again app stops.
App Works on some phones correctly, But in some another stops. Here is LogCat:

```
07-31 23:58:50.780: I/Process(10251): Sending signal. PID: 10251 SIG: 9
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.aiga.apps/ir.aiga.apps.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: queryInventory
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: queryInventory
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at ir.aiga.util.IabHelper.checkSetupDone(IabHelper.java:765)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at ir.aiga.util.IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(IabHelper.java:594)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at ir.aiga.util.IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(IabHelper.java:625)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at ir.aiga.apps.MainActivity$3.onIabSetupFinished(MainActivity.java:137)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at ir.aiga.util.IabHelper.startSetup(IabHelper.java:267)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at ir.aiga.apps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:129)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-31 23:58:50.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10251):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm that you are logged in with a valid Google account on all these devices?

Comment: Almost yes, No problem from this prespective!